# What do all the classes on my <html> tag mean?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

When I'm running my ASP.NET MVC site locally, the source of any page shows a seemingly ridiculous amount of CSS classes in the `<html>` tag.

```
<html class=" js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch 
    geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop 
    websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius 
    boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients 
    cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface 
    generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers 
    applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths">
```

Our site uses a number of frameworks, including jQuery, AngularJS, jqWidgets, and a few other small ones. Is it typical to have so many of these classes? And is there a way for me to find the source of each one? I don't like having so much overhead when I don't understand how it works.

Comment: some of the class would be used for resetting the default CSS provided by different browsers. You might be including some javascript library which would be adding the classes at runtime via code.

Comment: Yes, these classes are all added by one or some of your frameworks. These are definitely from something other than jQuery or Angular, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the work of [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs), a tool for detecting feature support in browsers. Here's a snippet from their docs (emphasis mine):

> By default,  **Modernizr sets classes for all of your tests on the root
>   element ( for websites)**. This means adding the class for each
>   feature when it is supported, and adding it with a no- prefix when it
>   is not (e.g. .feature or .no-feature).

This essentially lets you know which features are supported by that browser and allows you (and, presumably, Modernizr) to create some contextual CSS based on that information.

Apparently, you can disable this behavior. Check out their [configuration options](https://modernizr.com/docs#configuration-options)... particularly:

> `enableClasses` - *default: `true`*
>   Whether or not Modernizr should add its CSS classes at all